# PHP with Oracle Connectivity issue (Wamp 64bit + Windows 7)

Tags: php, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to connect PHP 5.6 with Oracle Database on windows machine via WAMP 64 bit server. I have downloaded OCI package from PECL website, put dll in ext folder and enable extension in php.ini file. Previously I got an error  while using the command oci_connect but after I do these settings I got the following error:

> Warning: oci_connect(): ORA-12541: TNS:no listener
>    and here is the code of my test script:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); 
$username = "hr";                  // Use your username
$password = "welcome";             // and your password
$connection_string="localhost/xe";
$conn=oci_connect($username,$password,$connection_string);

if($conn){
echo "connected";
}else{
echo "not connected";
}
```

MY question is how can i make a oracle database to use in this connection string?

Thanks

Comment: Check if the database engine is running.

Comment: Finally, fixed it by installing the Oracle Express Edition. Now it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like listener isn't started. Check it status at the operating system command prompt:

```
C:\Users>lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 07-OÄU-2020 22:38:28

Copyright (c) 1991, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener
   64-bit Windows Error: 2: No such file or directory
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=my_server)(PORT=1521)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener
   64-bit Windows Error: 61: Unknown error

C:\Users>
```

As you can see, the same error as you got. So, start it:

```
C:\Users>lsnrctl start

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 07-OÄU-2020 22:39:13

Copyright (c) 1991, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Starting tnslsnr: please wait...

TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production

<snip>

The command completed successfully

C:\Users>
```

Comment: thanks for these commands. Actually after installing Oracle Express Edition my issue is resolved

Comment: OK, I'm glad you solved it. Thank you for letting us know.